# Enable splash screen when app reopen cordova

Tags: android, cordova, process, android-manifest

Basically splash screen appears only once in the start[background process will start]. Currently when i reopen the application[background process does not close], i get a white screen and the app view.

Currently in my `config.xml` i have this

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="15000" />
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="2"/>
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true"/>
```

**How to show splash screen every time when i close and reopen the app?**

Answer (score 2):

Try out this preference. It's only for Android, and by default it's true:

```
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true|false" />
```

Also you can display the splashcreen on the [resume event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.resume.html):

```
document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
    console.log('EVENT resume');
    try{
        navigator.splashscreen.show();
    }
    catch(e){}
}, false);
```